# Not able to download JDK in C# program

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a C# program where I need to download `jdk` on the machine. I have written some code but it only downloads like 3-4 kb every time

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string address = "https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u211-b12/478a62b7d4e34b78b671c754eaaf38ab/jdk-8u211-windows-x64.exe";
    Uri uri = new Uri(address);
    var desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    string fileName = desktop + "\\jdk.exe";
    Console.WriteLine("Downloading file");
    client.DownloadFile(address, fileName);
    Console.WriteLine("Done Downloading File");
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: lol why would anyone want to download java stuff when you have C#

Comment: Sidenote: `async` and `await` are your friends, especially with larger downloads.

Comment: I must admit, downloading java in C# is like running away from the circus to join the orphanage. <this comment will self destruct>

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question which results in invalidating one or more Answers, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users should proactively revert such changes. I have done so here. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the address in a browser, you will quickly see why.

Downloading JDK8 requires you to be logged in now. They do this for older versions of Java. I believe JDK8 started this behavior about a month of so ago.

Comment: Oh ok I see. Do you know how I can automate the process of bypassing the sign in page? This code will work for other files however right?

Comment: @RohanJain Currently it should work with versions higher than 8, as they are still in development. You are not going to be able to bypass the Oracles sign-in page by any "normal" means. You can automate it if you have valid credentials. Either download it from somewhere else, or simply provide a link for the user to acquire it themselves if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The URL which you refer redirects to a SSO (Single Sign On) page of oracle site. Probably the 4kb data can be related to the web page and not .exe file. If you plan to automate the download make sure to pass username and password to the SSO page.